# Basic program termination

Tags: java, eclipse, if-statement

The program is designed to scan the user for the first two cards they receive and tell them what they have. Unfortunately, when it asks "Are the cards suited?: " it terminates before input can be taken. I also could learn how to organize the conditions in a switch statement rather than all these ugly if-else statements as well.

```
package Test;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Test {
public static void main(String[] args) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            int card1 = 0;
            int card2 = 0;
            String fc1, fc2;
            String answer;


            Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
            System.out.println("First card: ");
            if (scan.hasNextInt())
            {
                    card1 = scan.nextInt();
            }
            else
            {
                    fc1 = scan.next();

                    if (fc1 == "A")
                    {
                            card1 = 14;
                    }
                    else if(fc1 == "K")
                    {
                            card1 = 13;
                    }
                    else if (fc1 == "Q")
                    {
                            card1 = 12;
                    }
                    else if (fc1 == "J")
                    {
                            card1 = 11;
                    }
            }

            System.out.println("Second card: ");
            if (scan.hasNextInt())
            {
                    card2 = scan.nextInt();
            }
            else
            {
                    fc2 = scan.next();
                    if (fc2 == "A")
                    {
                            card2 = 14;
                    }
                    else if (fc2 == "K")
                    {
                            card2 = 13;
                    }
                    else if (fc2 == "Q")
                    {
                            card2 = 12;
                    }
                    else if (fc2 == "J")
                    {
                            card2 = 11;
                    }
            }

         if (card1 == card2)

         {
             System.out.println("You have a pair.");
         }
         else 
         {
        System.out.println("Are your cards suited?(y/n): ");
        answer = scan.nextLine();

             if (answer == "y")
             {
                 if (card1 >12 && card2 > 12)
                 {
                     System.out.println("High value suited cards.");
                 }
                 else
                     if (card1 == card2++ || card1++ == card2)
                     {
                         System.out.println("Suited connectors.");
                     }
             }
             else
                 if(answer == "N")
                 {
                     if (card1 >=12 && card2 >= 12)
                     {
                         System.out.println("High value cards, hold.");
                     }
                     else
                         if(card1 > 5 && card2 > 5)
                         {
                             if(card1++ == card2 || card1 == card2++)
                             {
                                 System.out.println("Connectors.");
                             }
                             else
                             {
                                 System.out.println("Fold");
                             }
                        if (answer != "y" || answer != "n")
                        {
                                System.out.println("Invalid entry.");
                        }
                     }
             }



         }
             }
```

}

Comment: using equals() instead of == for String/Object comparison.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read the [FAQ] and [Ask] for tips on writing good SO questions.  Have you tried running this in an IDE debugger and walking through the code one step at a time to see what's happening?  That should be your first endeavor.  In general, posting a bunch of code with no evidence you've made an effort to debug it yourself (i.e. tell us what you've done so far) is considered bad form.  Also, you _"could learn how to organize the conditions in a switch statement"_.  I'm sure you could, and that would involve just a few minutes reading about `switch` statements.

Comment: but what if the answer is either `Y` or `n`?

Comment: @Nambari so, how many times now do you think this question has been asked on stackoverflow?

Comment: On top of everything said in this question, for god's sake, use an enum!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: @Cruncher Yes, enums would work. However, if the asker is asking a question like this, and doesn't know how to use a switch statement... they won't know what an enum is, none the less how to make one xD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The program terminates because it takes the newline character the end-user added after the last integer as the end of the `nextLine()`.

Let's say the user enters `123` and presses <kbd>Enter</kbd>. At this point, the data in the buffer looks like this:

```
[1] [2] [3] [\n]
```

After you call `scan.nextInt()` the integer part is removed, but the `[\n]` remains in the buffer. When you call `scan.nextLine()`, that end-of-line marker is the first character the scanner sees, so it treats that `\n` as an empty string, which is returned to your program. You can fix it by calling `scan.nextLine()` before taking a full-line input.

However, this by itself will not fix your program, because you should be comparing strings using `equals()`, e.g. like this

```
if (fc1.equals("A"))
```

not like this

```
if (fc1 == "A") // <<== This will not work correctly
```